# JOptionPane show message dialog can not be closed in Focus Listener

Tags: java

As instructed in the reply to my earlier question I have added focus listener to my text fields.Now the text fields are selected when the tab key is pressed so it is ok. I have a JOPtionPaneShowMessageDialog in the NumberFormattedException handler to inform the user that the text fields should not be left blank. But now when the text field is blank the message appeared as usual, but it can not be closed.When it closed reopened at the same time. How can it rectified.Please help.

```
   public void focusLost(FocusEvent ae) {
}
   public void focusGained(FocusEvent ae) {
       Object source =ae.getSource();
           if(source instanceof JTextField) {
               gi.selectAll();
               hra.selectAll();
               ss.selectAll();
               pt.selectAll();

'.....code to execute....... '

}else if (source instanceof JButton) ;
    String w= (String) jcb.getSelectedItem();
try{
    String s1=gi.getText();
        int a=Integer.parseInt(s1);
            String s2=ss.getText();
                int b=Integer.parseInt(s2);
                    String s3=pt.getText();
                        int f=Integer.parseInt(s3);
                            String s4=sd.getText();
                                int h=Integer.parseInt(s4);
'....code to execute....'

}catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(jfrm, "No text field should not be left blank . 
        If no amount in a field put  0 (Zero) .", "WARNING ! ",1);
    }
}
public static void main (String args[]) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new IncomeTax();
        }
    });
}
}

'''


'Also I want to show JOptionpaneShowMessageDialog when the user click on the "Help" JMenuItem.My code for the same is as follows, but it is not working. Please give suggestion for the same also.

'''

}else if (source instanceof JMenuItem) {
     if(ae.getSource()== jmiHelp)
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"USER MANUAL\n"+"1.Select Age 
             Group.\n"+"2.Enter Gross Income(Salary/Pension)+Surrender Leave 
             salary+ interest income etc.)\n"+"3.Enter deductions admissible to 
             you.\n"+"4.Look tool tip texts for more details.\n"+"5.Click New 
             Scheme or Old Scheme for the respective tax calculation.\n"+"6.No 
             text fields should not be left blank.If no amount put zero.\n");
```

Comment: Format and indent your code properly.

Comment: What you mean by "format and indent the code". I am a very beginner, excuse me.

Comment: Remove the unnecessary vertical spacing between the code lines. Indent with leading spaces so that lines within `{ ... }` are indented properly.

Comment: Sir, the code now edited as instructed.

Comment: No. See this image for example: https://nullprogram.com/img/emacs/visual-indentation-mode-java.png

Comment: Please look at the now re edited code.

Comment: Still looks like a complete mess tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has resolved by myself. Instead of FocusListener ActionListener is used. Instead of tab key, enter key or mouse click for selecting text for first instance only. No problem for OptionPaneMessage's now.